# VueJs 2.0 - When press spacebar add/activate CSS Class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

A beginner question and not sure if vuejs can do this.

If you press a spacebar I want to add a css class. In this case to show the div

In this code I try something but that didn't work

```
  <div @keyup.space:class="show" tabindex="0" >test</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j7zoa2du/

Comment: press space bar in no where or in a input section?

Comment: @ZubaerHaque  yes just by opening the page. i put tabindex in there so it will be focus on that div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its should be like this

```
<div @keyup.space="activeClass=true" :class="{'mycls':activeClass}" tabindex="0" >test</div>
```

and in the data you should have

```
data(){
    return{
      activeClass:false
      //some other data you have
    }
  },
```

this will add the class `mycls` to div when spacebar is pressed (on the div)

Comment: Hi, i have traid with your code but didn't work. you can check it in here : https://jsfiddle.net/j7zoa2du/

Comment: take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/8h0qvcj9/46/ when you click on the div test (to focus) and then click on spacebar its will change the class of the div. dont forget that if you hide the div by dislay:none. you cannt press spacebar on it again.

Comment: your `data` property is not written correctly should be a function:
`data() {
  return {
    activeClass:false
  }
  },`

Comment: @Michael not really needed if the data is in the root vue instance :-)

Comment: looked at the docs, you are right although it's important not to make that mistake in most use cases.

Comment: @Michael absolutely

Comment: Do you have a url about the data property how it should be? because data(){return{} }that is something i didn't see..

Comment: @FT take a look https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function and https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

Answer (score 4):

The below example only works if the div (or any other element you want to add the `@keyup`) has the focus. If you want to trigger the events globally, it's worth checking out this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-global-events.

Once you added the package to your project, you could add this to your template section:

```
<GlobalEvents @keyup.space="activeClass=!activeClass"/>
```

to toggle the active class or set it to true alternatively.